# How to add pagination inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, modal-dialog

I have a `user's list`, when click on 'show activities' this shows a list of user activities in a modal from partial file `_user_activities.html.haml`. This activities list is a paginated view. I want to add pagination only for this activities alone inside my modal window. How to do this? I am already using `will_paginate`, that makes my page to reload. How to achieve this?

users/index.html.haml

```
%table
  %thead
    %th Name
    %th Actions
  %tbody
    - @users.each do |user|
      %tr
        %td= user.name
        %td
          %i.icon-play
          %div.modal.hide
            = render 'user_activities', user: user

= will_paginate users

:javascript
  $('i').click(function() {
    $(this).next(.modal).modal('show');
  });
```

users/_user_activities.html.haml

```
%table
  %thead
    %th Name
    %td Type
  %tbody
    - user.activities.eadch do |activity|
      %tr
        %td= activity.name
        %td= activity.type

= will_paginate user.activities
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve the ajax type pagination is with [Kaminary](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) gem. We can easily set up the pagination with Kaminary. I don't know how to achieve the ajax type pagination with `will_paginate`, but i used `kaminary` in my one of project and its quite easy with this.

**update**

Check [How to Implement ajax pagination with will_paginate gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623953/how-to-implement-ajax-pagination-with-will-paginate-gem) for providing the ajax type pagination with `will_paginate`.

Comment: my application is already using will_paginate. I don't want to use 'kaminari' for this specific purpose.

Comment: Thank You. This what I expected

Answer (score 0):

You can use kamiray or will_paginate gem very easy to use have a look at following example using will paginate,

do this in your controller and it will add pagination.

```
@set = SomeObject.paginate(:page       => params[:page],
                           :per_page   => 20,
                           :order      => 'created_at DESC',
                           :conditions => { :foo => 'bar' })
```

here is a railscast for [Kaminary](http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari) and [willpaginate](http://railscasts.com/episodes/51-will-paginate) 
Hope it would solve your problem.

Comment: I want to do this in table inside a modal window, not in ordinary page. I achieved pagination in my normal page using will_paginate

Comment: i believe if you have achieved pagination for normal page then it would be same when you would be using bootstrap. Otherwise you have to show your code.