# Pagination inside bootstrap modal window

Tags: pagination, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the bootstrap modal window as data picker. But when having more results to pick displaying pagination. I want to load the next pages inside the same modal window when clicking on the pagination.

Can I do it in generic way like when any link clicked inside a modal window to load the content inside the same modal window, or do I need to implement this for each link separately using AJAX feature?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this three links: There will help you for sure.

- [Reference-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787431/ajax-call-in-rails-3-2-3-with-will-paginate-gem/13975268)
- [Reference-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623953/how-to-implement-ajax-pagination-with-will-paginate-gem)
- [Reference-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631851/how-to-add-pagination-inside-a-bootstrap-modal)

Answer (score 0):

You could change `$('modal-body').html()` on click.

The modal shows/hide without changing or reloading content. So you will have to restore the original content on hide maybe.

Use `$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {}` to restore your original content.