# Ruby on Rails partial pagination issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

How can I use two paginations inside one page and make them work separately? For example, see the image below:

[image]

On the top of the image are two paginations: 1st on the left and the 2nd on the right. If I click on the 1st pagination, then I only need the data on the 1st pagination to load without the whole page being loaded; the 2nd one should stay the same and be separated.

Below is my controller code for the data shown:

```
@first= Post.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 4).order('post_id DESC')
@second= Post.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 4).order('post_id ASC')
```

Pagination `will_paginate`

Comment: what gem you are using for pagination?

Comment: `gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'`

Comment: If you want to load only specific part of the page, you have to rely on javascript (not sure if turbolinks would handle that very well, have a read on its documentation - i usually get rid of them in most of my projects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For separate loading you change your paginate params like `params[:page]` change to `params[:first]` second is same procedure & use your view page `<%= will_paginate @first, :param_name => 'first or second' %>` & then you try ajax page loading script for show result without whole page loading. you need create `index.js.erb` file inside your current page folder. this tutorial very nicely described [Pagination with AJAX](http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax?view=asciicast)

Hope will help you

Answer (score 0):

You have to set separate params name( instead one `page`)  for two section using

```
<%= will_paginate @first, :param_name => 'first' %>
<%= will_paginate @second, :param_name => 'second' %>
```

and on your controller you can write

```
@first= Post.paginate(page: params[:first], :per_page => 4).order('post_id DESC')

@second= Post.paginate(page: params[:second], :per_page => 4).order('post_id ASC')
```

You can see [will_paginate documentation](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/API-documentation)

Comment: Won't that still require a reload of the page?

Comment: If you wan't page loading then you have to use ajax. http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax

Comment: Hi, your code work exactly for separately but load all page. I need without page loaded

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623953/how-to-implement-ajax-pagination-with-will-paginate-gem this link can help you.