# Pagination on the same partial with different variables passed (will_paginate)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, partial-views, will-paginate

**How do I use pagination on the same partial with different variables passed?**

I have a library show page in my Rails app that has a list of books:

libraries_controller.rb:

```
def show 
  @books = @library.books.paginate(page: params[:books_page], per_page: 10)
end
```

libraries/show.haml:

```
#books_table
  = render "books_list", books: @books
```

libraries/show.js.erb:

```
$('#books_table').replaceWith('<%= j render "books_list", books: @books %>');
```

A 'books_list' partial has a pagination link which works fine:

books/_books_list.haml:

```
...
= paginate books, param_name: 'books_page'
```

When I add a new book to the list, `#books_table` is automatically replaced with `_books` partial like so (books/create.js.erb):

```
$('#books_table').replaceWith('<%= j render "libraries/books_list", books: @library_books%>')
```

books_controller.rb:

```
def create
  @library_book = @library.books.create(book_params)
  @library_books = @library.books.paginate(page: params[:books_page], per_page: 10)
end
```

But at this point pagination doesn't work. Any ideas how should I proceed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13639450/5117953 this might help you

Comment: Also use .html instead of .replaceWith